# Linking Access 2016 to excel sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to use the below code to link Access to Excel but keep getting " No files Found". I checked the location and it points to the file I am trying to link.

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

'code will link to excel and pull site survey files into access tables

'Setting the path for the directory

Sub LinkExcel()
Dim iFile As String 'Filename
Dim iFileList() As String 'File Array
Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number

Dim iPath As String

iPath = "C:\Users\mchattopad004\Documents\Files\TestGDAST.xlxs" 'Directory Path

'Loop through the folder & build file list
iFile = Dir(iPath & "*.xlxs")
While iFile <> ""
'add files to the list
intFile = intFile + 1
ReDim Preserve iFileList(1 To intFile)
    iFileList(intFile) = iFile
    iFile = Dir()
Wend

'see if any files were found
If intFile = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

'cycle through the list of files & link to Access
For intFile = 1 To UBound(iFileList)
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, , _
    iFileList(intFile), iPath & iFileList(intFile), True, "MA!A1:J3299" 'Set your range here.
Next

MsgBox UBound(iFileList) & " Files were Linked"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
iPath = "C:\Users\mchattopad004\Documents\Files\" 'Directory Path

'Loop through the folder & build file list
iFile = Dir(iPath & "*.xlxs")
```

Comment: Thanks! The issue was .xlxs extension. It worked with iFile = Dir(iPath & "*.xls")